# infinite scrolling with $http GET firing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
currentPage = 1;

$scope.loadPages = function () {

    Array.prototype.pushArray = function () {
        this.push.apply(this, this.concat.apply([], arguments));
    };

    if (currentPage < totalPages) {

        $scope.infiniteScoll = true;

        $http({
            url: "http://someurl.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                "topicId": $stateParams.topicId,
                "pageNumber": currentPage
            }
        }).then(function (response) {

            $scope.posts.pushArray(response.data);

            alert('w2');

            currentPage = parseInt(response.data[0].currentPage) + 1;
            totalPages = parseInt(response.data[0].totalPages) + 1;



        }).
        finally(function () {

            $scope.infiniteScoll = false;

        });

    }
}
```

I'd debug four hours, still couldn't know why is it firing twice. loadPages is my directive, if I delete everything within it and left only the alert('f'), it will only fire once. Perhaps I did something wrong else where?

Comment: try to scroll very slow, and check if it fired twice. If not => tell in comments, I had the same issue.

Comment: You can't try with an alert cause it's a blocking keyword.
Try with a simple console.log(). It could be a simple scrolling issue, just add a boolean and a "if block" on the top of your function which will stop the second calling and it will make the trick

Comment: @Rasalom I tried to scroll really slow, and my problem still occour. I'm very sure it wasn't my scroll directive problem, coz when I left only the alert in my $scope.loadPages, it triggered once.

Comment: @Polochon I don't think so, I try console.log with the $http and without the $http, the first one triggered once and the later triggered twice.

Comment: Well, anyway, try to block next request before previous was finished. You can do it by adding boolean param before api call and reseting it in response handler.

Comment: boolean param? for what?

Comment: sorry, I meant variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to block the second calling by using your infiniteScroll boolean like the following code

```
currentPage = 1;

$scope.loadPages = function () {

    //should be declared out of this function
    Array.prototype.pushArray = function () {
        this.push.apply(this, this.concat.apply([], arguments));
    };

    if(!$scope.infiniteScoll && currentPage < totalPages) {

        $scope.infiniteScoll = true;

        $http({
            url: "http://someurl.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                "topicId": $stateParams.topicId,
                "pageNumber": currentPage
            }
        }).then(function (response) {

            $scope.posts.pushArray(response.data);

            alert('w2');

            currentPage = parseInt(response.data[0].currentPage) + 1;
            totalPages = parseInt(response.data[0].totalPages) + 1;



        }).
        finally(function () {

            $scope.infiniteScoll = false;

        });

    }
};
```

Comment: var blocked? where else u use the blocked variable?

Comment: the "blocked" variable wasn't used (i deleted it), juste see the if statement

Comment: $scope.infiniteScoll is my loader. I use ng-show="infiniteScroll". Sorry if that confused u.

Comment: how could that loader troubled me? Can u explain bro? if it's $scope.infiniteScroll but just var infiniteScroll, do u think without the if not statement it will trigger twice?

Comment: it's not magic, the display condition of your loader is exactly what you need. When the function is the first time, we seal its behaviour and when the finally is triggered, we unseal it.
So, we don't care about how many calling were done during the loading, none of them can do anything

Answer (score 0):

Giving  `immediate-check="false"` on ion-infinite-scroll solved the issue for me.

Like this

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll
            immediate-check="false"
            on-infinite="loadMore()"
            ng-if="hasMoreData"
            distance="1%">
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```